# Direct access to Theory decision procedures using z3

Tags: c++, z3

Is there a z3 c++ api for direct query of a theory decision procedure?

Meaning, given a set of theory predicates, I would like to check whether they are conflicting in some given theory, without calling the z3 prover on their conjunction.

For example, I would like to check whether the following set of predicates in equality logic are conflicting:
x=y, y=z, x!=z

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use some tactics, depending on what parts of the theories exactly you need (see [Z3 Strategies](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies)).

If you want only very quick no-solving-at-all checks, then you should use the simplifier, it will apply the rewrite rules for all theories and return a simplified expression, which could be either true or false. The rewriter is also used to evaluate expressions given some model, so it supports everything that is needed to evaluate an expression when all the variable/constants/functions have an interpretation (and model completion can be enabled to fill in the missing ones).